# CakePHP in sub-url (not sub-directory)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, cakephp

I can find dozens of articles on installing CakePHP in a sub-directory and getting it to appear in the root url. That is **NOT** what I am asking for. I rarely down-vote, but if you give that answer, I will down vote you.

I have CakePHP in my root directory on my hosting server. It's a clean Apache server instance... I think. I'm really not a server guy. I created a new account through WHM on Hostgator and have CakePHP sitting in the public_html.

However, there is no domain name associated with this server yet. The URL is like this:

`http://123.456.0.0/~example/`

And CakePHP gives me the following errors:

```
Error: ~exampleController could not be found.

Error: Create the class ~exampleController below in file:
app/Controller/~exampleController.php
```

I imagine there's some .htaccess configuration that makes it ignore that `/~example` in the URL. Can someone point me in the right direction, even if it's just the right page in the CakePHP docs?

Comment: Do you have a virtual host set up? You should be able route requests with an apache directive.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html - scroll down to ip-based virtual hosting.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to this but if virtual hosts are not an option and you absolutely must use the /~username/ format then you can Google for answers for installing cake in the "UserDir" -- "UserDir" is the term used by Apache to describe /~username/ access. There is an article at http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/syl-via/2011/09/19/rewritebase_config_for_cake_installation_with_userdir_and_mod_rewrite about this but I already tried the advice there and it didn't work for me. Perhaps you could try it and maybe it will work for you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By partially following the advice at http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/syl-via/2011/09/19/rewritebase_config_for_cake_installation_with_userdir_and_mod_rewrite I was able to make this work by adding the following to the .htaccess file in the root of the Cake install:

`RewriteBase /~example`

I put this *after* `RewriteEngine on` for it to work.

In other words, if your Cake install is at `/home/example/` then it's the `/home/example/.htaccess` file that you'd change.

I didn't edit `app/.htaccess` or `app/webroot/.htaccess` because it seems to work without these files needing to be edited.

Please note that I tested this with the latest version of Cake (2.3.5) -- I don't know if it will work the same way in older versions.

Comment: How do i do the same for IIS server without the support of URL rewrite module.